# insert Rad Grid Command Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in asp.net and i'm using RadControls for Asp.net Ajax now. I tried to follow the Asp.Net GridDemo - Insert/Update/Delete and it seems to be not all working pretty fine with me so i did few changes and turned out to be somehow doing well but the insert button still not working and for the update button it is working fine with a very small issue...

I have 1 view viewFacilitiesMaster and 2 tables tblCity and tables tblBranch

In my Radgrid i only wanted to display the facility, facilityID,city,cityID, Branch, BranchID from the view.

I'm using web user control as EditFormType. And in my Edit Form :AddFacility.ascx. The only editable region is the facility (radTextbox),city (dropdownList) and branch (drop down list)

(Note that ddlCity display the list of a hotel cities and ddlBranch display the Hotel City related branches)

My problem is when i hit the insert Button it doesn't work.. -_-,

Here's my code

**frmFacilityMaster.aspx**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvS" runat="server" DataSourceID="tblFacilities" 
GridLines="None"   AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
Width="99%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowStatusBar="True" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" 
OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand" 
OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" 
OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand" Skin="Black" 
ShowGroupPanel="True" onitemcommand="gvS_ItemCommand">     
<HeaderContextMenu EnableTheming="True">
<CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
</HeaderContextMenu>
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#E1DED2" />
<MasterTableView autogeneratecolumns="False" datasourceid="tblFacilities"
EditMode="PopUp" commanditemdisplay="Top" >
<RowIndicatorColumn>
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>
<ExpandCollapseColumn>
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>
<GroupByExpressions>
<telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
<SelectFields>
<telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="City" FieldName="City" HeaderText="Hotel  
City"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
</SelectFields>
<GroupByFields>
<telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="City"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
</GroupByFields>
</telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
<telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
<SelectFields>
<telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="Branch" FieldName="Branch" HeaderText="Hotel  
Branch"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
</SelectFields>
<GroupByFields>
<telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Branch"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
</GroupByFields>
</telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
</GroupByExpressions>
<Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NameAr" HeaderText="Name (Ar)" 
SortExpression="NameAr" UniqueName="NameAr">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
SortExpression="Description" UniqueName="Description">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Amount" DataType="System.Decimal" 
HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" UniqueName="Amount">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="cityID" HeaderText="City ID" 
SortExpression="cityID" UniqueName="cityID" Visible="true">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="branchID" HeaderText="Branch ID" 
SortExpression="branchID" UniqueName="branchID" Visible="true">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="facilitiesID" DataType="System.Decimal" 
HeaderText="facilitiesID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="facilitiesID" 
UniqueName="facilitiesID" Visible="False">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
<ItemStyle Font-Italic="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#CC3300" />
</telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
<telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="find" HeaderText="" 
Text="Delete" UniqueName="column">
<ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Underline="True" 
ForeColor="#CC3300" />
</telerik:GridButtonColumn>   
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DescriptionAr" HeaderText="DescriptionAr" 
SortExpression="DescriptionAr" UniqueName="DescriptionAr" Visible="False">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="createdDate" HeaderText="Created Date" 
SortExpression="createdDate" UniqueName="createdDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="updatedDate" HeaderText="Updated Date" 
SortExpression="updatedDate" UniqueName="updatedDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
<EditFormSettings UserControlName="addFacilityForm.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl"  
CaptionFormatString=" Add Facility Form" FormStyle-Font-Bold=true >
<FormStyle Font-Bold="True"></FormStyle>
<PopUpSettings Width="70%" />
<EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
</EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>              
<ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
</ClientSettings>            
<FilterMenu EnableTheming="True">
<CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
</FilterMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**AddFacility.ascx**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="25%">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=" Hotel City"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">   
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" DataSourceID="tblCity" 
            DataTextField="city" DataValueField="cityID" AutoPostBack="true" 
            SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval( Container, "DataItem.cityID") %>' 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="tblCity" runat="server" ConnectionString="<% $ ConnectionStrings:SmartBookingEngineConn %>" SelectCommand="select cityID,city from viewCityAdmin"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=" Hotel Branch"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBranch" runat="server" DataSourceID="tblBranch"
            DataTextField="Branch" DataValueField="BranchID" SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval( Container, "DataItem.BranchID") %>'>

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="tblBranch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SmartBookingEngineConn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BranchID],[Branch] FROM [tblBranch] WHERE ([CityID]=@cityID)">
           <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="cityID" ControlID="ddlCity" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
           </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="25%">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Facility"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFacility" Runat="server" 
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container, "DataItem.Name"  ) %>' 
            Width="250px">
        </telerik:RadTextBox>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**AddFacility.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class addFacilityForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private object _dataItem = null;
    public object DataItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dataItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this._dataItem = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

set telerik grid's properties **AllowAutomaticUpdates or AllowAutomaticDeletes or AllowAutomaticInserts to true**...

Comment: Still Not Working, But Note if i remove this SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval( Container, "DataItem.BranchID") %>'   from AddFacility.ascx then the insert bill work but when editing there is no selected value in these dropdownlists: